# clang-format columnlimit return type on new line

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Symptoms of my code are as follows.

```
bool
doSomething(int a, int b, int c, int dd, int eee, int fffffffff, int gggggg, int hhhhhhhhhhhh, int iiiiiiiiiii);
```

I Want

```
bool doSomething(int a, int b, int c, int dd, int eee, int fffffffff, int gggggg,
                 int hhhhhhhhhhhh, int iiiiiiiiiii);
```

As much as possible, the format currently in use should not be affected.
The format I am currently using is as follows.

```
    ---
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: Google

IndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
AccessModifierOffset: -4

ColumnLimit: 120

DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
...
```

Answer (score 0):

- That example line is less than 120 characters, so it will format all on one line unless you change ColumnLimit. That's probably not the point of this question, but regardless, you need to set ColumnLimit to anything between 81 and 98 to get your example line broken exactly where you ask. I'll suggest `ColumnLimit: 90` because it's a round number.
- You need to use `BinPackParameters: true`
- You need to use `AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align`

That should be all you need to change.

Note, I tested this using the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/), which is a great place to experiment with different clang-format versions and style options.